# Gradle DSL method not found: 'compileSdkVersion()' after importing a module into the project

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, import-module

I have a project in Android Studio. I need to import a module in this project: https://github.com/square/android-times-square/
There is a library and a sample in this packege. I import both of them.
I download .zip and in Android Studio do **File -> New -> Import Module**
And after that I get the graddle error:

```
Error:(16, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'compileSdkVersion()'
Possible causes:
The project 'MyProject' may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method 
(e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0).
Upgrade plugin to version 2.3.3 and sync project. The project 'MyProject' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Open Gradle wrapper file. The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply Gradle plugin
```

I have clicked all the links listed in this error message. But it did not help.
**What's wrong in gradle scripts?**
I don't understand why there are so many gradle files **and which one I need to fix** (((

build.gradle (MyProject)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

ext {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle (library)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'checkstyle'

task checkstyle(type: Checkstyle) {
  configFile rootProject.file('checkstyle.xml')
  source 'src/main/java'
  ignoreFailures false
  showViolations true
  include '**/*.java'

  classpath = files()
}

afterEvaluate {
  if (project.tasks.findByName('check')) {
    check.dependsOn('checkstyle')
  }
}

android {
  compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
  buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
  }


  lintOptions {
    warning 'MissingTranslation'
    textReport true
    textOutput 'stdout'
  }
}

dependencies {
  testCompile deps.festandroid
  testCompile deps.junit
  testCompile deps.robolectric
  testCompile deps.intellijannotations
}

apply from: rootProject.file('gradle/gradle-mvn-push.gradle')
```

build.gradle (sample)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
  buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility rootProject.ext.sourceCompatibilityVersion
    targetCompatibility rootProject.ext.targetCompatibilityVersion
  }

  defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'com.squareup.timessquare.sample'
    minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
    targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode 1
    versionName '1.0.0'
  }

  lintOptions {
    disable 'MissingTranslation'
  }
}

dependencies {
  compile project(':library')
}
```

build.gradle (module:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myproject.myproject2"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

settings.gradle

```
include ':app', ':sample', ':library'
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> Error:(16, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'compileSdkVersion()'

You can't use this syntax in the top-level file:

```
ext {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25
}
```

Instead you can use this syntax (pay attention to `=` )

```
ext {
    // The following are only a few examples of the types of properties you can define.
    compileSdkVersion = 25
    buildToolsVersion = "26.0.1"
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you.I changed the top-level file (I left only compileSdkVersion and buildToolsVersion).

Comment: And I also changed gradle files for modules, because options rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion and rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion were causing new error (they do not exist). I changed them to numbers. Now there is another problem: Error:(46, 1) A problem occurred evaluating project ':library'.
> Could not get unknown property 'deps' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Comment: @Evgenia My script is just an example. You can use also `minSdkVersion`,`targetSdkVersion` but use the same syntax with `=` as reported above.

Comment: Thanks again! I haven't noticed that the diffeence is in using "=". I have commented out the block with "deps" (dependencies in the library gradle file - I will fix or replace it later, when I will understand what it is responsible for) and everything worked!!! Thank you very much!!!